# wait for async function ends

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've my own function A, and a third party async function B that upload a file, now I would like to call function B during the execution of A, and then wait that B function ends.

I can check if the function is completed by a flag var F, the problem is that if I use the below code the browser go in an endless loop(maybe because it is busy in the loop and cannot update F).

```
function A(){
    // ...
    B();
    while(F);
    // ...
}

function B(){
    // ...
}
```

I cannot split the function A in 2 sub-functions

Sorry for my very poor english

Comment: _I cannot split the function A in 2 sub-functions_ Why not?

Comment: That's what *promises* are for. If `B` is properly implemented it should return a promise object that you can use to set up handlers that are invoked when the async process in `B` is finished. Alternatively they might have added an argument to a function to call once `B` is finished. However, if the implementors of `B` have been lazy, they haven't done anything like that and there's not much you can do really.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` runs always in one thread. It means, that you cant do a busy wait, or you will block the entire script. You should use some async programming. Like providing a callback to your `B` function or letting your `B` func return a promise.

The callback approach will look like this:

```
B(function(err, result) {
    // some code after B completes
});
```

Function `B` must call the callback after completion.

When using promises, your code will be like:

```
B().then(function(result) {
        // result handling
    }, 
    function(err) {
        // error handling
    });
```

Promises are very handy, but require to use some third party library, as they are not a part of `JS`. In fact, using a promises may differ, depending on library (i.e. promises in `jquery` and `q`)

Comment: `not a part of JS` - unless you use a browser using the spidermonkey, v8, or chakra javascript engines - which covers all modern browsers and nodejs thrown in

Comment: I know callback and promises tecniques, but with these tecniques I should split the A function in 2 sub-functions, the problem is that the A function is too complex and splitting it in 2 I would send so many attributes from first part to second part, also the division in my case would be right in the center of a while loop(not shown in the example)